# Return String Generated by PHP Webpage

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I have a url like the following:

http://www.test.co.uk/Requests.php?accessToken=01XJSK

Depending on wether or not the access token is valid, either a 1 or 'invalidAT' is returned.  However when I try to return that value, I end up returning HTML and not the string.

This is what I am currently trying:

```
- (NSString *) getDataFrom:(NSString *)url{

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];

    NSError *error = [[NSError alloc] init];
    NSHTTPURLResponse *responseCode = nil;

    NSData *oResponseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&responseCode error:&error];

    if([responseCode statusCode] != 200){
        NSLog(@"Error getting %@, HTTP status code %i", url, [responseCode statusCode]);
        return nil;
    }

    return [[NSString alloc] initWithData:oResponseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
}
```

Can anyone explain how I go about returning either the '1' or the 'invalidAT'?

Comment: Perhaps setting the content type of the php-result to text/plain may help: header("content-type: text/plain");

Comment: this shouldn't be flagged with `PHP`

Comment: This is because the web page returns an html string. Instead return plain text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are being returned with iFrame source with

`http://lvps92-60-123-84.vps.webfusion.co.uk/Requests.php?accessToken=01XJSK`

You have to call this URL and you will get response.

In browser this run perfectly because of iFrame is getting executed.

Answer (score 2):

The url you give as an example "http://www.sonect.co.uk/Requests.php?accessToken=01XJSK", returns html with a frame that has "http://lvps92-60-123-84.vps.webfusion.co.uk/Requests.php?accessToken=01XJSK" as it's source:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>

<head>
 <title>www.sonect.co.uk</title>

</head>
<frameset rows="100%,*" border="0">
  <frame src="http://lvps92-60-123-84.vps.webfusion.co.uk/Requests.php?accessToken=01XJSK"  frameborder="0" />
  <frame frameborder="0" noresize />
</frameset>

<!-- pageok -->
<!-- 02 -->
<!-- -->
</html>
```

That source will return `1` as response.